# java regular expression on nested word count

Tags: java, regex

I have String of text that i need to find does it have the nested loop or not Can i use regular expression to find the nested loop counts ?

So my example of text is :

```
Library-Bookshelf-Book-Book-EndBookShelf-BookShelf-Book-EndBookShelf-Library
```

I want to search for: `Whether the String belongs to the Library that has more than 1 Bookshelf in one at least has more than 1 books ?`. Would it be possible with regular expression. I appreciate any other ideas. thanks.

So input is the above example string. Required  output would be first match found. I need to split these for the first occurrence.

```
Bookshelf-Book-Book-EndBookShelf
BookShelf-Book-EndBookShelf
```

But my regular expression returning:

```
Bookshelf-Book-Book-EndBookShelf-BookShelf-Book-EndBookShelf
BookShelf-Book-EndBookShelf
```

Test case 2:

```
Library-Bookshelf-Book-author-author-location-Book-author-EndBookShelf-BookShelf-Book-author-EndBookShelf-Library
```

with the regular expression i need to find whether the bookshelf in a library has more than 2 books and in that  for one book it has more than one author. 
Tescase 2 should return one match because the first part  Bookshelf-Book-author-author-location-Book-author-EndBookShelf satisfy the condition.

Thanks..

Comment: please explain what the input is and the expected output is

Comment: Added an example. Thanks

Comment: is it always guaranteed that if there is `Bookshelf` then there will always be `EndBookshelf` ?

Comment: yes, But for the Book there is no end element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Regex: `Bookshelf-(?:Book-)*EndBookShelf`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/voSMy2/2)

Comment: This returning two matches on my input String.. But how can restrict to return only one in the regular expression ? I mean to say to return only one match that have at least 2 books.

Comment: @user3342678, could you please edit the post to add the string to match and the expected output.

Comment: @user3342678, is this what you are looking for `Bookshelf-(?:Book-){2,}EndBookShelf` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/voSMy2/3)

Comment: This is helpful. if i want to add another sibling element to book like an author .. some books may have more than one author.. would it be possible to add that to above expression ?   ex: `Library-Bookshelf-Book-author-author-location-Book-author-EndBookShelf-BookShelf-Book-author-EndBookShelf-Library`   ..

Comment: @user3342678, please edit the post to add all of the requirements

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String x = "Library-BookShelf-Book-author-author-location-Book-author-EndBookShelf-BookShelf-Book-author-EndBookShelf-Library";
    List<String> bookShelves = fun(x, "BookShelf", "EndBookShelf");
    for (String book : bookShelves)
    {
        List<String> authors = null;
        if(book.indexOf("Book") == book.lastIndexOf("Book"))
            authors = fun(book, "Book", "Book");
        else
            authors = fun(book, "Book", "EndBookShelf");
    }
}

public static List<String> fun(String input, String startTag, String endTag){

    String [] c = input.split("-");
    List<Integer> shelfIndices = getIndices(c, startTag, endTag);

    List<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i=0;
    while (i<shelfIndices.size()-1)
    {
        int start = shelfIndices.get(i);
        int end = shelfIndices.get(i+1);
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        res.append(startTag+"-");
        for (int j=start+1; j<end; j++)
        {
            res.append(c[j]+"-");
        }
        res.append(endTag);
        answer.add(res.toString());
        i+=2;
    }
    for(String r: answer)
        System.out.println(r);
    return answer;
}

public static List<Integer> getIndices(String [] c, String startTag, String endTag){

    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++)
    {
        if (c[i].equals(startTag) || c[i].equals(endTag))
        {
            indices.add(i);
        }
    }

    return indices;
}
```

this prints out

```
BookShelf-Book-author-author-location-Book-author-EndBookShelf
BookShelf-Book-author-EndBookShelf
Book-author-author-location-EndBookShelf
Book-author-EndBookShelf
```

Comment: Thanks, I could use index of BookShelf and copy the part of string ..And my end goal is validating it has more than one book .. or more than abutor for one book  (see updated testcase).  thanks for the reply.